# não consigo recuperar uma imageview no (R.drawable)

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, drawable

Era para aparecer (***R.drawable.image1***) para que eu recuperasse ela mas sempre da esse erro na classe R.não sei mais o que fazer se alguem puder me ajudar nessa situação...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente é por que falta importar a lib R.

Vai na linha onde ta o erro aperta "alt + enter" e importa a primeira lib que aparecer

Comment: funcionou muito obrigado